# Trying to create a private area custom for each user where they upload images to a server

Tags: plugins, javascript, plugin-recommendation, server

I have quite a bit of experience writing Python, but I'm trying to create a website for the first time using wordpress. I really like the user area that this site offers: https://www.ponoko.com/

and I was wondering how you guys would recommend going about recreating the "My Ponoko" portion of the site?

A list of things I'm trying to do include:

- Users log in to their account in order to access the submission area.
- Users can upload files that only they (and the admin) can access.
- When users log in in the future their previous uploaded files will be 
  available to them.
- The images are processed by some javascript on the server, and a double value is returned.
- Users will pick out a material to put the image on.
- Users are charged a price that is a function of the double returned from the javascript.

Are there plugins available that I could use to do all of these things? If so, which ones? How do I set up the database used to store the uploaded images?